# Custom UITableViewCell does not show it's contents

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

In Xcode 5.1, using StoryBoards, I'm having trouble getting a custom UITableViewCell to show it's contents. The cell appears -- I can tap to select it -- but the label text doesn't appear.

I've given the Cell my custom class GCell and identifier MyCell

I've connected an IBOutlets to a label in the prototype cell.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@end
```

In my class that extends UITableViewController, I have

```
@implementation PayGroupViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] initWithStyle");

    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

  //  [self.tableView registerClass:[GCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    _groups = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

    GroupModel *gm = [[GroupModel alloc] init];
    gm.title = @"DINNER";
    gm.names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    [gm.names addObject:@"Me"];
    [gm.names addObject:@"Albert"];
    [_groups addObject:gm];

    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] viewDidLoad. [self groups].count:%d" ,[self groups].count);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] tableView. [self groups].count:%d" ,[self groups].count);
    return [self groups].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    GCell *c = (GCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    GroupModel *group = [self.groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] group.title: %@",group.title); // Outputs "DINNER"

    c.nameLabel.text = group.title; // It does not show up
    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] cell: %@",c); // outputs <GCell: 0x9976ed0, etc. so it does exist
    NSLog (@"[PayGroupViewController] cell.nameLabel: %@",c.nameLabel); // outputs (null)

    return c;
}
```

Also, here is the entire xCode project if anyone cares to take a look.

http://www.brainjelly.com/WhoPaid.zip

Note that the prototype cell has a Disclosure Indicator Accessory, but that doesn't appear either.

Thanks… I've looked extensively over the other posts with this issue but none of those solutions helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your xCode project.

1. You shouldn't register custom cell class in your code for prototype cells. Storyboard does that for you. When you register same class, you are basically overriding the one created by storyboard.
2. In your prototype cell there is an undefined outlet named "title", which is connected to Content View. Define or delete it.

After these, clear the project and recompile, it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks ujell! I didn't think I needed to register the custom cell class, but that allowed it to build (and had seen it on previous projects -- .xib based I believe). Is there anyway to run through a project and check that there are no "loose-end" IBOutlets?

Comment: As far as i know there isn't any easy way and xCode doesn't give you a warning but if there is a problem with IBOutlets, storyboard inspector shows an exclamation mark like in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/HTN76tD.png .